# Node no quiere funcionar

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Verán, tengo un extraño problema con node que hace que a veces no se ejecute sin ningún motivo.
Por ejemplo, tengo este sencillo código:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Creamos una estructura de datos.
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, edad) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.edad = edad;
  }
  saludar() {
    return (
      '<p>¡Hola, ' +
      this.nombre +
      ' ' +
      this.apellido +
      '! ¿Que tal a tus ' +
      this.edad +
      '?</p>'
    );
  }
}

// Creamos un array para almacenar los objetos y ponemos un ejemplo.
const array = [];
array.push(new Persona('Paco', 'Miraflores', 45));

// Dirección web base. Se limita a mostrar la lista de usuarios.
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let texto = '<h1>Lista de usuarios</h1>';
  console.log('Prueba correcta');
  if (array.length > 0) {
    array.forEach((element) => {
      texto += element.saludar();
    });
  } else texto += '<h2>Esta lista esta vacia</h2>';
  res.send(texto);
});

// El usuario puede introducir aquí los datos de la nueva persona.
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  array.push(new Persona(req.body.nombre, req.body.apellido, req.body.edad));
  res.send('¡Usuario introducido con exito!');
});

// Modificaremos aquí el último usuario introducido.
app.put('/', (req, res) => {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    array[array.length - 1] = new Persona(
      req.body.nombre,
      req.body.apellido,
      req.body.edad,
    );
    res.send('¡El último usuario introducido ha sido modificado!');
  } else res.send('¡No hay ningún usuario en la lista!');
});

// Limpiamos por completo la lista.
app.delete('/', (req, res) => {
  array.length = 0;
  res.send('¡Lista vaciada correctamente!');
});

// Por si se produce un error.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.end('¡Error 404!');
});

// Iniciamos la página web en localhost.
app.listen(4000, () =>
  console.log('El servidor se ha iniciado en el puerto 4000'),
);
```

Esto me mostrará en el client una lista de personas, pudiendo introducir nuevos usuarios entre otras cosas.
También tengo este package.json:

```
{
  "name": "intro-to-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Con todo esto, escribo en mi terminal `yarn start` para encenderlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aparentemente va bien, por lo que me voy a Postman para probarlo, pero...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si, algo va mal que me impide conectarme. Es raro, simplemente enciendo el ordenador y aparece el problema cuando no pasaba antes de apagarlo, y si apago el PC y me espero, al regresar el problema se ha solucionado.
Aún así, ¿alguien sabe que esta pasandome?

Comment: no deberías ejecutar `node ./nombreFicheroExpress.js`?

Comment: Cuando haces el request con postman. ¿Te aparece algo en la consola donde estas ejecutando node?

Comment: @hawks El error sigue apareciendo si hago eso.

Comment: @FranAcuna En la consola no aparece ni un solo mensaje de error. Solo en el Postman.

Comment: En el postman donde te sale el error al lado hay el botón de "View in console" si clicas quizá te de mas información

Comment: ¿@MiguelAlparez Estás utilizando algún proxy? (Puede ser el de postman, que está en opciones, si está activado, pureba desactivándolo)

Comment: Por el momento se ha solucionado. Ya si veo que vuelve a fallar mirare lo que me habéis contado.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que chequees que no es un error de Postman, probalo con curl o algo por el estilo

También comprobá que tu server sigue vivo despues de la request con Postman, cuando hay un error en nodejs sin `catch` el programa finaliza solo

Aparte:

Hay un error en tu código, en `array.length = 0`.

la propiedad `length` de los arrays es de solo lectura.

Podes cambiarla por `array = []` o `array.splice(0, array.length)`.

Te recomiendo la primera opción.